# Does passing param to constructor better than to static method

Tags: java, oop, constructor, static

Assume that I have a class Example:

```
public class Example(){
    public static String method1(String param){...}
    public static String method2(String param){...}
}
```

If my client want to call both of those 2 methods: they would do something like this:

```
String param = "Hello";
String result = Example.method1(param);
...
String result2 = Example.method2(param);
```

And now It turns me a question, should this code better if we pass param in Example class's contructor and call those 2 methods without any param, something like this:

```
 public class Example(){
     String param;
     public Example(String param){
         this.param = param
     }
     public String method1(){...}
     public tring method2(){...}
 }
```

And the client just calls:

```
Example example = new Example("Hello");
String result = example.method1();
String result2 = example.method2();
```

I'm wondering if the 2nd is better than 1st one. Because in my opion the 2nd one is more *OOP* and easier to use when we don't need to pass multiple input param?
Could anyone give me an advice?

Comment: I guess it depends on what your code is used for.

Comment: If `Example` only has these 2 methods and the methods are *always* called with the same parameter then it might make sense

Comment: If param is a constant value that is important for the created object, pass it in the constructor. If it might be different for any methodX() call, it's a parameter.

Comment: Do you need to be able to `new Example("foo").method1(); new Example("bar").method2();`? If so, then the instance don't have sense. An instance is not just there to store a variable, it is there to represent an entity.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is better at ensuring consistency of `param` between the two calls, because the value of `param` is set once in the constructor, and does not change after that.

The first approach (with two static methods) gives you flexibility to switch the value of `param` in between of the two calls.

The second approach protects you from that (assuming that it would be a mistake to pass different `param` to the methods in a sequence of calls).

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what your methods are doing it and whats your code requirement. Assume you want a String variable available to both these methods, you can initialize in in a constructor. But, since you have static method which are not closely tied to Object instead class and they can operate on different inputs from different classes, having parametrized static methods isn't bad either.

In the end, it all just depends on your case and code functionality.